# Handle Redirects for Facebook Profile Images with FancyBox 2

Tags: jquery, facebook, fancybox, fancybox-2

OK, so we are using the awesome [FancyBox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox) to put together a carousel of user images.

Everything is working great for images on our servers and other servers, with the exception of Facebook profile images.

- We get the following back from [Janrain](http://janrain.com) linking to this: `https://graph.facebook.com/648845765/picture?type=large`
- You will see that if you hit that in your browser, you end up on Akamai: `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/371305_648845765_1960948885_n.jpg`
- The problem is that FancyBox doesn't seem to cope well with that and just doesn't display the image.

I've put together a demo [here](http://codepen.io/robcthegeek/pen/kstpK). Note the following:

1. I'm using a normal image hosted on the Interwebs as image #1.
2. I am using the problematic URL for #2.
3. I have used the resolved Akamai URL for #3.
4. **Only images 1 and 3 display in the carousel**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out - came across [this](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/304) in the GitHub Issues.

> you just have to specify content type, because the script can not guess

Adding the class `fancybox.image` to the `A` tag sorts it.

I've updated the Pen and all is well.